# How to apply and configure the Kotlin No Arg compiler plugin in Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#no-arg-compiler-plugin) only gives an example in Groovy DSL:

```
plugins {
  id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.noarg" version "1.3.31"
}

noArg {
    annotation("com.my.Annotation")
}
```

How does this translate into Kotlin DSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Kotlin DSL is statically typed, the syntax will differ slightly from Groovy DSL.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.noarg.gradle.NoArgExtension

plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.noarg") version "1.3.31"
}

configure<NoArgExtension> {
    annotation("com.my.Annotation")
}
```

Differences:

- Kotlin DSL requires `id`s in the `plugins` block to accept an argument of the plugin id.
- The plugin exposes the type `NoArgExtension` which is then imported. It's required for the `configure` block in which the plugin can be configured similar to the Groovy DSL.

Comment: Please explain *what* your snippet does and how it addresses the problem